# Merge en columna de valor con columna de lista

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Sea `df`

```
   nombre     codigo
0  daniel     [1, 3]
1   diana  [2, 3, 5]
2   sebas        [3]
3   marta     [4, 6]
```

y `df_2`

```
   codigo   concepto
0       2     objeto
1       3  asterisco
2       4    perfume
3       5    aspecto
4       6        pez
```

Quisiera hacer un `merge()` con las columnas "codigo" de tal forma que un nombre del primer dataframe haga match con un concepto del segundo (el primero que aparezca, por lo que imagino que podría usar algo con `any()`).

Mi resultado final se vería algo así

```
   nombre     codigo   concepto
0  daniel     [1, 3]  asterisco
1   diana  [2, 3, 5]     objeto
2   sebas        [3]  asterisco
3   marta     [4, 6]    perfume
```

(Si se puede hacer match con todos los códigos que tiene un nombre, sería un buen adicional)

Por ahora tengo:

```
def get_first_choice(campo,df_2):
    df = df_2[(df_2["codigo"].isin(campo))]
    if len(df):
        return df["concepto"].iloc[0]
    return ""

df["concepto"] = df["codigo"].apply(lambda x: get_first_choice(x, df_2))
```

Es muy fácil hacer esto iterando por el dataframe, pero imagino que sería demasiado lento para archivos más grandes. ¿Existe una mejor forma con `merge`?

Comment: Lo pregunté aquí también: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65444396/how-can-i-combine-two-dataframes-based-on-a-column-of-lists-in-pandas

Comment: @zabop excelente!! Te parece si traduzco la respuesta para cerrar la pregunta? O prefieres hacerlo tú? No tendría ningun problema

Comment: Publíquelo ahora, siéntase libre de corregir mi gramática.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import pandas as pd
```

---

Si usted tiene:

```
df=\
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'nombre':['daniel','diana','sebas','marta'],
                        'codigo':[[1, 3],[4, 3, 5],[3],[2, 6]]})


df2=\
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'codigo':[1,3,4,5,6],
                        'concepto':['elemento','asterisco','perfume','aspecto','pez']})
```

Usando [esto](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65444441/8565438):

```
df.explode('codigo')\
  .merge(df2, on='codigo', how='left')\
  .dropna(subset=['concepto'])\
  .drop_duplicates('nombre')
```

Resultando:

```
   nombre codigo   concepto
0  daniel      1   elemento
2   diana      4    perfume
5   sebas      3  asterisco
7   marta      6        pez
```

Tenga en cuenta que esto se basa en no tener entradas duplicadas en la primera columna.

Answer (score 2):

```
import pandas as pd
```

---

Si usted tiene:

```
df=\
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'nombre':['daniel','diana','sebas','marta'],
                        'codigo':[[1, 3],[4, 3, 5],[3],[2, 6]]})

df2=\
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'codigo':[1,2,3,4,5,6],
                        'concepto':['elemento','objeto','asterisco','perfume','aspecto','pez']})
```

Tu puedes hacer:

```
df['primer']=df['codigo'].apply(lambda row: row[0])
df.drop(columns='codigo',inplace=True)

df['primer']=df['codigo'].apply(lambda row: row[0])

df.set_index('primer',inplace=True)
df2.set_index('codigo',inplace=True)

res=df.join(df2)
```

`res` será:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

o, en vez de `join`:

```
res = pd.merge(df,df2,right_index=True,left_index=True)
```

`res`:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si:

```
df2=\
pd.DataFrame.from_dict({'codigo':[1,3,4,5,6],
                        'concepto':['elemento','asterisco','perfume','aspecto','pez']})
```

luego, siguiendo el mismo procedimiento descrito anteriormente:

`df.join(df2)` será:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

`pd.merge(df,df2,right_index=True,left_index=True)` será:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Buena respuesta, pero disculpa, olvidé aclarar que en el campo "codigo" del primer dataframe no necesariamente va a tener su contraparte en el df2. Por ejemplo, qué hacemos si no existe el codigo=1 en el `df2` ?

Comment: Edité mi publicación. Ahora bien, si no hay coincidencia para el primero, será NAN, que no es ideal. No marca el segundo elemento de la lista (es decir, 6), lo siento.

Comment: Dale, igual le sirve a alguien si tiene una pregunta similar!